# How to set height of UITableView cell dynamically using Autolayout?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I had taken two view inside content view.
Height of "Post Container View" (Red background) is calculated dynamically as per height of label (All done using Autolayout).

Now I want that if height of "Post Container View" (Red background) will increase then height of cell view auto increase. I want to do this using autolayout.

I want to calculate height of UITableview cell using Autolayout. How to do it ?

[image]

Cell Height = Post Container View (Flexible as per label height)+ Image Container View Height (300 Fix)

I had seen this type of method, but dont know how to implement in my code ?

```
- (CGFloat)calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:(UITableViewCell *)sizingCell
{

    sizingCell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(self.MyTableView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(sizingCell.bounds));

    [sizingCell setNeedsLayout];
    [sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize size = [sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height + 1.0f; // Add 1.0f for the cell separator height
}
```

Comment: please see the update

Comment: not getting, please brief it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate height of cell :

```
CGFloat height ; // take global variable

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      height = cell.PostContainerView.frame.size.height ;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    height = height + 300 //(300 is Fix height of Image Container View ) ;
    return height ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to calculate the height, or the tableView to calculate the height itself, considering your autolayout configuration ?

To do so, don't implement the delegate method *heightForRowAtIndexPath* but *estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath* instead (with whatever value you want for the moment).

The tableView will determine the height of the cell considering autolayout constraints applied on it.
Be warned that sometimes you need to call *layoutIfNeeded* on your cell, after you updated it. (for exemple in the *cellForRowAtIndexPath*)

Comment: I want to increment height of TableViewCell, but what constarint I have to do for it.

Comment: Considering your actual configuration and the use of my explanations, your cell should be resized well. Also check that you set "0" to numberOfLines of your label (multiline).
You can check that it should work by changing the height constraint of your Post Container View programmatically (having an IBOutlet of your NSLayoutConstraint and playing with the _constant_ property), and see the cell height change.

Comment: I had given all the constaraint for Post Container View and label, which works fine, Now my posint is, height of cell how will be calculated when height of Post Container View will increase ?

Comment: I want Cell Height = Post Container View (Flexible as per label height)+ Image Container View Height (300 Fix)

Comment: Did you try to refresh the row ? By calling _reloadData_ or _reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:_ . And don't forget to call _layoutIfNeeded_ on your cell before returning it in _cellForRowAtIndexPath:_

Answer (score 0):

Use this `Extension` class for string:

```
import UIKit

extension String {       
    func sizeOfString (font: UIFont, constrainedToWidth width: Double) -> CGSize {
        return NSString(string: self).boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: width, height: DBL_MAX),
            options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
            attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font],
            context: nil).size
    }   }
```

In `UITableView` delegate calculate `UILabel` width:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {        
        let item = "hkxzghkfjkgjkfxkj jjhghdjajfjkshgjkhkkn jhkhhgdfgjkhsfjkdghhhsxzgnfshgfhk jhsfgfhjfhghj "
        let widthOfLabel = Double(view.frame.size.width) - 30
        let textHeight = item.sizeOfString(UIFont.systemFont(14), constrainedToWidth: widthOfLabel)
             return (padding + textHeight.height)
     }
```